# How can you see a variables snapshot of an azure yaml pipeline run?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

For a classic release pipeline, in Azure Devops you can easily see a snapshot of the variables and values for each pipeline run. How can you see this if you use a multi stage full yaml pipeline?

Comment: What have you tried?  FWIW, if you mean by logging, then maybe something like this could help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable

Comment: Look at the commit. That's your snapshot.

Comment: @DanielMann, I have variables added thru linking variables groups plus added directly thru the UI via the provided Variables button, there is nothing in the commit.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround I specificall added a custom task (ShaykiAbramczyk.printAllVariables.printAllVariables.printAllVariables@1) to print out the variables. This way you can see a Print Variable task on your runs. It will not print secrets as expected. This does the job, least until Devops team implementes this feature.

Comment: Awesome extension - perfectly displays variables in Azure Devops build logs with a single line of yaml

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the snapshot of the variables defined in yaml file of pipeline run. You can check the yaml file of the commit that related to the pipeline run as Daniel mentioned.

[image]

If you have variables defined in the **Variables** tab in the pipeline UI page. You can see the variables snapshot from the `History` tab.

click the 3 dots of the yaml pipeline edit page and choose Triggers

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have a full yaml pipeline. How do you get that view with tabs YAML, Variables, Triggers, History?

Comment: You can get that view by click the `3 dots` of the yaml pipeline edit page and choose `Triggers`, see above screenshot.

Comment: I see. But this at the pipeline definition level. But after the pipeline runs, I don't see a way stage varaibles linked from variables groups.

Comment: I see the problem too, You can [submit a user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) to microsoft development team. Hope they will implement this feature on yaml pipeline too.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT - This answer only applies to custom variables. What about build variables and system variables?