# Is there a way to determine what parameters were used for running an Azure Pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've found the following block:

```
stages:
- stage: Print_Params
  jobs:
  - job: Print_Params  
    steps: 
    - ${{ each parameter in parameters }}:
      - script: echo ${{ parameter.Key }} ${{ parameter.Value }}
```

But it invokes CmdLine once for each specified parameter.  I'd really like to have a single screen I can look at to review all the parameters that a pipeline was invoked with.  Is this built in, and there's a place I can already review it, or is there a way I can invoke the loop within a script to print all of the parameters in a single execution?  I've tried a number of different syntaxes and nothing I've tried so far is working.

Comment: There are some possible solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62782885/how-can-you-see-a-variables-snapshot-of-an-azure-yaml-pipeline-run

Comment: Hi Derian, Does below beatcracker's solution work? Please check it and kindly let us know the result.

Comment: @EdwardHan-MSFT: It works, but with a few caveats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can view runtime parameters, queue time variables and job preparation parameters in Azure Pipelines UI:

[image: Azure Pipelines UI1]

Comment: This works, but with some caveats...  Scheduled and automatically triggered runs don't seem to print this information.  In these cases it would be using default values, so I guess it's not truly necessary, but it would be nice to have as a reference.