# How can I see the Azure DevOps YAML Pipelines classic/GUI variables' initial values?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

We have many YAML pipelines that are running in Azure DevOps. We are still using the classic/GUI variables for some values. However, we don't know how to view these variables' starting values. We're looking for some pipeline setting that we can toggle to log the initial value of the variables before it continues on to our pipeline jobs.

Here's what we're currently seeing:
[stage startup logs with 5 standard lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPaXr.png)

One of our runs, we're not sure how, did log all the variables as "queue time variables", but research here hasn't been fruitful. This is what we'd like to see for every run:

[queue time variables logged at stage startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63wa7.png)

We've looked at [How can you see a variables snapshot of an azure yaml pipeline run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62782885/how-can-you-see-a-variables-snapshot-of-an-azure-yaml-pipeline-run) and [Define variables - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch), but neither seem to fully answer the question.

Is this still unsupported as a setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying the variables.. you can use a bash task. in GUI you can add inline script as 'env | Sort'

```
steps: # 'Steps' section is to be used inside 'job' section.
  – task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 'env | sort'
```

Hope this helps!